# Apple Two Factor Authentication: why verification code popup don't display?

Tags: icloud, security, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I turned on Two Factor Authentication mode, it worked very well. But yesterday, I reinstalled my Macbook, and iPhone, verification code popup don't automatically display when I login new device. I must get code through text message, or manually getting verification code from iCloud setting. I logged both iPhone, and Macbook, but all don't show popup (I also try to log from another pc but same result).

I’m using Mac OS 10.12.3, and iOS 10.2.1

I think two cases:

1. It's a problem occurred when I reinstalled my device.
2. Someone (may be a "hacker") controlled my apple ID and my devices. (I'm worry about this!)

Comment: What happens when you request the code by text message? Comment back with `@owlswipe` so I can help you more!

Answer (score 1):

When you restore a device, it is removed from the trusted device list in case you want to sell it. Here's how you can add the iPhone back to the list:

Go to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) and sign in.

Under security, go to Trusted Devices.

Refresh devices then follow directions to confirm your device.

Remove your unused versions of devices.

You will only be able to receive codes on your iPhone, not your mac.

Comment: Thanks, but I also removed iphone or mac os from devices lists, and signing again (it is added again to trusted devices list), it still doesn't work.

Comment: @wellbeck190 so you do not see the devices as options in the 2FA list?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "2FA list" meaning.

Comment: Two my devices (iphone and mac book) were listed in devices list of apple id page, I can see device info, and I also see message "This device is trusted and can receive Apple ID verfication code", but both don't work.

Comment: The 2FA list is the list of devices you can choose from when you sign in, @wellbeck190.

Comment: When I signin from anywhere (macbook, iphone, web browser), it always require verification code, but verification code popup don't display on other devices. I must request text message code, or manually get message code from iCloud setting.

Answer (score 0):

There’s also the possibility you need to just enter your password and then tack on the verification code 6 digits as if that was part of your password, at the end, with no spaces between the actual password and the code.

- [Getting prompted for verification code but where do I put it in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357218/getting-prompted-for-verification-code-but-where-do-i-put-it-in)

I would reach out to Apple support in case you are being attacked or there’s another explanation, though. If this doesn’t work - might be worth checking into trusted devices and change your password to be safe.